# Is there any performance Impact of using spring boot web app with JDBC ignite instead of dot NET native approach of connecting to ignite?

Tags: java, .net, spring, jdbc, ignite

Currently we are using the dot NET(c#) code to connect to Apache Ignite cluster using native approach as mentioned here [dot NET Apache Ignite native client approach](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs).

Now we have planned to migrate this dot NET code to Spring boot web app (Java) using [JDBC approach of connecting to Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver)  but wanted to know doing this same  will it have any performance drawbacks/benefits as compared to dot Net Native client approach of connecting to Apache Ignite ?

Comment: Can you share the reason for migration?

Answer (score 3):

Native .NET client runs JVM in process and interacts with it directly through shared memory.

JDBC Thin driver connects to Ignite node through a TCP socket, which is slower in general and has more overhead.

But you should measure your specific use case to make a decision.